# Remove border on horizontal list item on second line

Tags: css, html-lists

I have rather an odd query.

I have a horizontal list of links that use borders to simulate a 'pipe' separator, that can split over two lines - see http://jsfiddle.net/gfkPG/162/

I want the first item of the second line to not have a 'pipe' separator. That is, I want this effect: [image]

I do not know what the length of each link will be in advance, nor do I know how many links there will be, or whether I will even have enough links for more than one line in the first place. Therefore I cannot arbitrarily set a class on a particular item.

I cannot absolutely place an image over the borders of the left items, because my background colour is not always white - sometimes it is a coloured gradient.

Are there any ways to do this in pure CSS? If not, are there any Javascript solutions?

I have heard of a CSS clipping property, but I'm told it doesn't work on older browsers (and my solution needs to support IE7+). I'm stumped for alternatives.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's messy, but this might work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul class="list">
     <li>This is a list item</li>
     <li>This is a list item</li>
     <li>This is a list item</li>
     <li>This is a list item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu{overflow:hidden;}
ul#list{margin-left:-1px;}
ul#list li{border-left:solid 1px;}
```

Comment: Why was this an accepted answer? The doesn't solve the issue with text wrapping onto a second line and forming an a second border in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me if you know how wide the items will be. If you know there will always be three (or whatever) per line, you could use the [nth-child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).

Comment: I will not know how wide the items will be (the text varies under different circumstances), no - only the order.

Answer (score 0):

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gfkPG/163/

Style the li tag so that it has border:none

Comment: This won't work for me - I don't know the number of items, or their length. Therefore, I cannot arbitrarily apply a 'no border' class to a particular li element. See http://jsfiddle.net/7WgsA/1/

Comment: I'd suggest using javascript then